# Excel->SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-addin, excel, excel-services

So I have a huge excel spreadsheet, with multiple lists and columns, how would I incorporate this into my SharePoint website as a new link? I know how to add an app, etc...but how do I add the spreadsheet with everything still intact with the different pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You upload each table as a separate list into SharePoint. However by the sounds of it this may not be the best solution as your excel document sounds quite complicated. You may have to do a bit of fiddling to get any connections and formulas right.

To export a given table into SharePoint click on the table and go to the table tab (Design) and click export > export table into SharePoint

Comment: This might be my best bet. I didn't know if there were any simpler ways but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the spreadsheet in a document library and on the landing page of you SharePoint site, place the document library list view web part or you can just edit the page and insert a hyperlink and reference the Excel sheet.

Comment: So there's no way to keep the formatting going from excel to SharePoint? I want the document to become a SharePoint list then from SharePoint to export to excel.

Comment: if you have Excel Services installed on your environment, you can use it :

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Getting-Started-with-Excel-Services-and-Excel-Web-Access-fed3586d-b150-4819-a67e-14529c974387?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US